# Python: How much memory does attribute takes?

Tags: python, variables, memory, attributes, space

is there a function in Python which can find out how much memory takes a certain attribute or a variable?

EXAMPLE:

```
a='ThisTakesSeveralBitesOfMemory'
print(a.memoryTaken())

>> 20 b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.getsizeof()`. It returns in bytes.

```
>>> a='ThisTakesSeveralBitesOfMemory'
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
50
```